# Without using MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

can anyone suggest me how to send SMS without using MFMessageComposeViewController. is it possible, if possible how can i do that. pls suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to implement a SMS Gateway @ server end.
make service on server that accepts phone numbers and optionally "message string".
call that service from your device and pass the numbers with optional "message string".

your server can then send SMS to the specified numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:123456789")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
                if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendAttachments() {
                    print("canSendAttachments")
                }
                let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
                messageVC.recipients = ["123456789"]
                messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
               messageVC.accessibilityActivate()
                self.present(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("Cant send sms")
            }
        }
```